# How to terminate a batch file upon encountering an error in Mongodb command?

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, scripting

I am using this batch script containing:

```
mongo.exe mydb < D:\TFX\Delta\script.js
```

How can i terminate this batch script if any command from file 'script.js' give error in execution, say,
my file contains:

```
db.runCommand( { <command> } )
db.adminCommand( { <command> } )
```

And any of these command throws error, so how can i terminate the whole batch script.

Comment: I'm sure theres likely a solution to be found by reading through the documentation Surrounding [Log Messages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/) and [Exit Codes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/)

Comment: let me see, thanks.